# Could some one please explain why this below program is crashing?

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

Simple vector push operation

```
int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(4);
  for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
       i != v.end(); i++) {
    cout << *i << endl;
```

I could not understand what is happening at this below point

```
    if (*i == 1) {
      v.push_back(5);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: People here are going to want to know the failure mode.

Answer (score 13):

`push_back()` invalidates your iterator. Using it in your loop like this is an error because `i` does not need to have anything to do with `v` after `push_back()`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is as stated in the other answer.  If you really wanted to `push_back(5)` for every item in the vector that is equal to 1,  the following code would have worked:

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iterator>

    using namespace std;
    int main() 
    {
       vector<int> v;
       v.push_back(1);
       v.push_back(2);
       v.push_back(3);
       v.push_back(4);
       v.push_back(1);
       v.resize(v.size() + std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), 1), 5);
       std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    }
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 1 5 5
```

Basically, it's all accomplished in a single line of code using the `resize()` member for `vector`.  The `std::count` counts up the number of entries in the vector equal to 1.  Then the original vector is resized, and have the new elements set to 5.

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis:**
`v.push_back(5)` **might** reallocate the storage place if the new vector size exceeds its  capacity (Refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).  **If** this happens, all the iterators are invalidated.  This causes your exception.

**3 Solutions:**

(1) If you do not need to continue the iterations (i.e. you have to add a single item after the first occurence), then you could just add a `break;` after the conditional pushback() in order  to interrupt the loop.  THe rest of your programme will run without crash.

(2) If you know in advance that you might have to pushback AT MAXIMUM n elements, then you could simply increase the vector capacity in advance, before your iteration, with `v.reserve(v.capacity()+n);`

(3) The last possibility, if you are in the dark about potential insertions, then you shoud check the iterator position BEFORE the insertion, and then reloop to that position after the insert. This is done at a proportional performance cost but it works.  The if clause would look like:

```
if (*i == 1) {
    cout << "op..."; 
    int j=i-v.begin(); 
    v.push_back(5);
    cout<<"Break the iteration at position " << j <<endl; 
    i=v.begin(); 
    for (++j; j; j--) 
        i++;
    }
```

I've tested all three solutions with VC 2013 and they seem to work.

Comment: If in case (1), the code from @PaulMcKenzie is much more elegant. Case (2) and (3) are only relevant if your sample code is supposed to perform more complex processing in the loop.